# Cross Validation, weight initialization and early stopping in spacy 3.0 without using config

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy for a text classification problem and need to achieve the following in code:

1. early stopping
2. cross-validation
3. set seed for weight initialization

For cross-validation, I am currently manually calling the `evaluate` function on the validation dataset after each epoch. Something like:

```
for i in range(25):
    losses={}
    
    for batch in minibatch():
        nlp.update(batch, optimizer, losses=losses) #need a way to provide early stopping param and seed for weights here
    
    print(losses['textcat'])
    
    #validation phase
    score = nlp.evaluate(validation_data_set)
    print('validation score', score)
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically (without using the *.cfg file)? I am having some issues using that as of now

Comment: I strongly recommend using the config based training instead of your own training loop. You can set a seed in the config, and control early stopping using the `patience` setting. You do not pass a seed to `nlp.update`, that would no sense since it's only used at initialization.

Comment: For cross validation specifically, spaCy doesn't handle it. The easiest way to do it is to call training multiple times with different data splits you prepared outside of spaCy.

Comment: @polm23 in that case how do i save my data in the spacy format? My training data is a list of tuples where each tuple contains the text and one hot encoded categories. Something like: [(text, {'cats': {label1: true, label2: false....}})]

Comment: @polm23 also calling training on the validation set i have will update the weights as well. Validation ser is supposed to be used only for checking progress during training, right? Is my current implementation incorrect? Also i see there's a 'dev' key in the config which takes the path of a dataset, is it not used for validation?

Comment: To make training data, you just build a list of docs and save a docbin. The textcat sample projects might be helpful, like this script. https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/v3/tutorials/textcat_goemotions/scripts/convert_corpus.py

Comment: spaCy uses the terms "train set" and "dev set", see the docs here for more details. https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data

Comment: The spaCy course is also really good at giving an overview of all of this. https://course.spacy.io/en/